# Controller always received null arguments

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My contact controller action always receives a null object. What am I missing?

### The Controller

(I have added breakpoints at the mail.Body assignment, and the entire message object is null)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contact(ContactMessage message)
{
    var mail = new MailMessage();
    var client = new SmtpClient("localhost");
    mail.From = new MailAddress("************");
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("****************"));
    mail.Subject = "New Message from *************.com";
    mail.Body = message.Message;

    client.Send(mail);

    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

### The Model

```
public class ContactMessage
{
    [Required]
    [PlaceHolder("john.smith@example.com")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [PlaceHolder("John Smith")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [PlaceHolder("I am interested in...")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public bool Delivered { get; set; }

    public ContactMessage()
    {
        this.Delivered = false;
    }
}
```

### The javascript being fired in the view

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#contactForm").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this);

            if ($form.valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Contact",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { Name: 'boom', EmailAddress: 'pow', Message: 'boom boom pow' }
                }).success(function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        alert("success");
                    } else {
                        alert("not success");
                    }
                }).fail(function () {
                    alert("fail");
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have also tried sending data with Postman - but that also seems to result in a null object.

[image]

---

## Update

I have made a few changes (and progress)but am still having issues.

Following **Paul Zahra's** advice on bad naming, the class in now ContactData (not ContactMessage)

By following **ekad's** answer, the message object is no longer entirely null, rather, a ContactMessage object with null `Name`, `EmailAddress`, and `Message` properties.

I have also added the contentType property thanks to **ramiramilu's** and **ekad's** answers

Updated code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contact(ContactData data)
{
    var mail = new MailMessage();
    var client = new SmtpClient("localhost");
    mail.From = new MailAddress("************");
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("************"));
    mail.Subject = "New Message from ************.com";
    mail.Body = data.Message;

    client.Send(mail);

    return Json(new { success = true });
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#contactForm").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this);
            var msg = { Name: "boom", EmailAddress: "pow", Message: "boom boom pow" };

            if ($form.valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Contact",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ message: msg }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                }).success(function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        alert("success");
                    } else {
                        alert("not success");
                    }
                }).fail(function () {
                    alert("fail");
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: BTW - you don't need to set `this.Delivered = false;` in the constructor. Default value of `bool` is `false`.

Comment: public ActionResult Contact(ContactMessage message) ... you are not posting the message object to your controller. *Wondering why you are using ajax to send an email anyway, what's wrong with the normal view post / form attribute method.*

Comment: You have a Message inside a message, that can't be right unless you want it to be recursive, naming can mean a lot.

Comment: @PaulZahra I updated my class name based on your advice (good point, by the way). I don't think I fully understand your first comment though, Can you elaborate more on what you mean by not posting the message object to the controller? Or has that been resolved by my update/ekad's answer?

Comment: @anywyatt If you define the model (@model message - so the view knows the type of the model) of the view to be of type message, when you post back to your controller the message object and any values are passed automagically (mapped) to the controller (parameter) in one neat operation (as far as your concerned) using your message object throughout the entire process (as long as you are not using complex objects as things can get a bit messy / wrong (which your message object is not)). Using JSon / Ajax to achieve this seems to me to muddy the water a little.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `message` in the controller action method is not a javascript primitive type, you need to use `JSON.stringify` when passing the parameters. Change your javascript as below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#contactForm").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this);
            var msg = { Name: "boom", EmailAddress: "pow", Message: "boom boom pow" };

            if ($form.valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Contact",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ data: msg }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                }).success(function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        alert("success");
                    } else {
                        alert("not success");
                    }
                }).fail(function () {
                    alert("fail");
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, the parameter name (`data`) inside `JSON.stringify` method from the code above:

```
JSON.stringify({ data: msg })
```

must be the same as the parameter name of `Contact` action method in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Contact(ContactData data)
```

Comment: Progress! Now, message is not completely null, but has null properties. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Double quotes instead of single for msg values?

Comment: The above code will only send `Name`, `EmailAddress`, and `Message` properties. If you want to send value to the other properties you need to add the value to the `msg` variable.

Comment: @ekad those 3 properties are coming through as null.

Comment: @anwyatt try to change the single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: @greatbear302 no dice on switching from single to double quotes.

Comment: @anwyatt try to set `contentType` option in the `$.ajax` syntax

Comment: @drewwyatt how did you end up fixing / resolving the null properties? I am having this same strange issue

Answer (score 2):

In the JQuery Code, set -

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

**EDIT**

I tried with this class -

```
public class ContactMessage
{
    [Required]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public bool Delivered { get; set; }

    public ContactMessage()
    {
        this.Delivered = false;
    }
}
```

Then I simplified your controller action -

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(ContactMessage message)
    {
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

Then I simplified your query code -

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var msg = { Name: "boom", EmailAddress: "pow", Message: "boom boom pow" };

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/home/Contact",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ message: msg })
                }).success(function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        alert("success");
                    } else {
                        alert("not success");
                    }
                }).fail(function () {
                    alert("fail");
                });
    });
```

When I run the code -

[image]