# Parameters on Url.Action() have null properties

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, visual-studio-mac

I have the following code:

```
onClick="location.href='@Url.Action("StampPdf", "EditPdf", new {pView = currentPdfView})'" />
```

which when clicked calls a method called `StampPdf(PdfView pView)` on a controller called `EditPdfController`. The controller method is called, with the variable pView, but instead pView has all its properties equal to `null`. It's as if the PdfView class has been instantiated afresh. Within my cshtml razor file, currentPdfView is instantiated and has all properties with values assigned to them, but in the controller the properties are null.

[This user here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25976512/870565) had the same issue, but there is no followup on whether it was resolved or not.

Is there something I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Could you show more code for details :))

Comment: I'm not sure how well it can handle complex objects like you have here. You may need to break them into multiple properties with simple values, or use a form POST to submit them.

Comment: @juunas actually that could be the reason. I could serialise the complex object into json. A model is probably a better approach.

Comment: @juunas could you please post your comment as an answer. You were right regarding the complex objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't know how to serialize the model into a query string :)

You need to break your model into multiple properties with simple values, or use a form POST to submit them as a model.

You can also serialize the model into e.g. JSON and pass it as a string.